# Undesired output when subsetting data in R

Tags: r, subset

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong. I would like to subset rows 673 to 15424 from a dataframe called `dataresults`. You can see even when using `head()`, R isn't selecting the rows I would like to be selected:

```
> head(dataresults[671:676,])
    Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude     step   x   y        z
710 2018-06-20 02:28:00 -2.441108  34.80987 4911.931 159 120 200.0218
711 2018-06-20 02:32:00 -2.441089  34.80983 4915.523 194 164 256.0309
712 2018-06-20 02:36:00 -2.441044  34.80987 4910.948 150  98 179.2751
713 2018-06-20 02:40:00 -2.441044  34.80988 4909.571 211  97 233.0782
714 2018-06-20 02:44:00 -2.441088  34.80983 4915.852 184 161 245.9219
715 2018-06-20 02:48:00 -2.441056  34.80988 4910.120 190 153 246.4066
```

In the example above, I ask to show rows 671 to 676 on my command, but I get rows 710 to 715 for some reason.

When I try to subset data, something similar happens as you can see below. It's not subsetting starting at row 673, but at 712:

```
> datacorr<-dataresults[673:15424,]
> head(datacorr)
    Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude     step   x   y        z
712 2018-06-20 02:36:00 -2.441044  34.80987 4910.948 150  98 179.2751
713 2018-06-20 02:40:00 -2.441044  34.80988 4909.571 211  97 233.0782
714 2018-06-20 02:44:00 -2.441088  34.80983 4915.852 184 161 245.9219
715 2018-06-20 02:48:00 -2.441056  34.80988 4910.120 190 153 246.4066
716 2018-06-20 02:52:00 -2.441082  34.80987 4911.728 144 165 220.2726
717 2018-06-20 02:56:00 -2.441079  34.80992 4905.648 150 129 198.1244
```

Here's a sample of `dataresults`:

```
> dput(dataresults[600:800,])
structure(list(`Date & Time [Local]` = structure(c(1529444640, 
1529444880, 1529445120, 1529445360, 1529445600, 1529445840, 1529446080, 
1529446320, 1529446560, 1529446800, 1529447040, 1529447280, 1529447520, 
1529447760, 1529448000, 1529448240, 1529448480, 1529448720, 1529448960, 
1529449200, 1529449440, 1529449680, 1529449920, 1529450160, 1529450400, 
1529450640, 1529450880, 1529451120, 1529451360, 1529451600, 1529451840, 
1529452080, 1529452320, 1529452560, 1529452800, 1529453040, 1529453280, 
1529453520, 1529453760, 1529454000, 1529454240, 1529454480, 1529454720, 
1529454960, 1529455200, 1529455440, 1529455680, 1529455920, 1529456160, 
1529456400, 1529456640, 1529456880, 1529457120, 1529457360, 1529457600, 
1529457840, 1529458080, 1529458320, 1529458560, 1529458800, 1529459040, 
1529459280, 1529459520, 1529459760, 1529460000, 1529460240, 1529460480, 
1529460720, 1529460960, 1529461200, 1529461440, 1529461680, 1529461920, 
1529462160, 1529462400, 1529462640, 1529462880, 1529463120, 1529463360, 
1529463600, 1529463840, 1529464080, 1529464320, 1529464560, 1529464800, 
1529465040, 1529465280, 1529465520, 1529465760, 1529466000, 1529466240, 
1529466480, 1529466720, 1529466960, 1529467200, 1529467440, 1529467680, 
1529467920, 1529468160, 1529468400, 1529468640, 1529468880, 1529469120, 
1529469360, 1529469600, 1529469840, 1529470080, 1529470320, 1529470560, 
1529470800, 1529471040, 1529471280, 1529471520, 1529471760, 1529472000, 
1529472240, 1529472480, 1529472720, 1529472960, 1529473200, 1529473440, 
1529473680, 1529473920, 1529474160, 1529474400, 1529474640, 1529474880, 
1529475120, 1529475360, 1529475600, 1529475840, 1529476080, 1529476320, 
1529476560, 1529476800, 1529477040, 1529477280, 1529477520, 1529477760, 
1529478000, 1529478240, 1529478480, 1529478720, 1529478960, 1529479200, 
1529479440, 1529479680, 1529479920, 1529480160, 1529480400, 1529480640, 
1529480880, 1529481120, 1529481360, 1529481600, 1529481840, 1529482080, 
1529482320, 1529482560, 1529482800, 1529483040, 1529483280, 1529483520, 
1529483760, 1529484000, 1529484240, 1529484480, 1529484720, 1529484960, 
1529485200, 1529485440, 1529485680, 1529485920, 1529486160, 1529486400, 
1529486640, 1529486880, 1529487120, 1529487360, 1529487600, 1529487840, 
1529488080, 1529488320, 1529488560, 1529488800, 1529489040, 1529489280, 
1529489520, 1529489760, 1529490000, 1529490240, 1529490480, 1529490720, 
1529490960, 1529491200, 1529491440, 1529491680, 1529491920, 1529492160, 
1529492400, 1529492640), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Latitude = c(-2.43975, -2.43975, -2.4397322, -2.4397025, 
    -2.4397319, -2.4397222, -2.4397503, -2.4397319, -2.4397603, 
    -2.4397786, -2.4397308, -2.4396814, -2.4397206, -2.4396697, 
    -2.4396711, -2.4396208, -2.4396028, -2.4396211, -2.4396203, 
    -2.4397194, -2.4397186, -2.4397006, -2.4397003, -2.4397008, 
    -2.4396917, -2.4396903, -2.4397003, -2.4396997, -2.4397197, 
    -2.4397106, -2.4397014, -2.4396922, -2.4397108, -2.4397014, 
    -2.4397294, -2.43973, -2.4397214, -2.4397306, -2.4397306, 
    -2.4397117, -2.4397014, -2.4397214, -2.4397206, -2.4396933, 
    -2.4397111, -2.4397283, -2.4397844, -2.4398364, -2.4398647, 
    -2.4399486, -2.4400481, -2.4400575, -2.4400642, -2.4400847, 
    -2.4400661, -2.4400553, -2.4400639, -2.4400658, -2.4400761, 
    -2.4400731, -2.4400567, -2.4406367, -2.4407722, -2.4407828, 
    -2.4406792, -2.4409539, -2.4410103, -2.4410028, -2.4409719, 
    -2.4411133, -2.4410883, -2.4411075, -2.4410886, -2.4410444, 
    -2.4410444, -2.4410878, -2.4410556, -2.4410825, -2.4410789, 
    -2.4411061, -2.4411144, -2.4411061, -2.4411144, -2.4411497, 
    -2.4411156, -2.4411147, -2.4411128, -2.4411217, -2.4411336, 
    -2.4411358, -2.4411228, -2.4411144, -2.4411242, -2.4411128, 
    -2.4411036, -2.4411228, -2.4411147, -2.441125, -2.4411164, 
    -2.4410969, -2.4411081, -2.4411325, -2.4411344, -2.4411431, 
    -2.4411256, -2.4411247, -2.4411436, -2.4411167, -2.4411361, 
    -2.4411236, -2.4409958, -2.4409711, -2.4410139, -2.4410156, 
    -2.4410422, -2.4410425, -2.4410497, -2.4409417, -2.4409728, 
    -2.4409736, -2.4407436, -2.4407433, -2.4404333, -2.4403611, 
    -2.4403361, -2.44011, -2.4396039, -2.4393222, -2.4393864, 
    -2.4392581, -2.4392686, -2.4392058, -2.4390514, -2.4389414, 
    -2.4386886, -2.4386139, -2.4385608, -2.4385161, -2.4384967, 
    -2.43847, -2.4382892, -2.4382442, -2.437855, -2.4379953, 
    -2.4379356, -2.4378919, -2.4380156, -2.4380969, -2.4384147, 
    -2.4386289, -2.4385756, -2.4386211, -2.4389197, -2.4389389, 
    -2.4390017, -2.4391189, -2.4392058, -2.4392514, -2.4393181, 
    -2.4393031, -2.4393031, -2.43933, -2.4393042, -2.4393303, 
    -2.4393044, -2.439385, -2.4394014, -2.4393125, -2.4393028, 
    -2.4394925, -2.4395019, -2.4395744, -2.4396292, -2.4396289, 
    -2.4397903, -2.4397878, -2.4399094, -2.4399719, -2.4400533, 
    -2.4401081, -2.4400794, -2.4400447, -2.4400525, -2.4401358, 
    -2.4401708, -2.4400719, -2.4400789, -2.4400711, -2.4400244, 
    -2.4401439, -2.4405497, -2.4405506, -2.4405864, -2.4405881, 
    -2.4406842, -2.4405864, -2.4405406, -2.4402969, -2.4401425, 
    -2.4400511, -2.4400744), Longitude = c(34.8093553, 34.8093553, 
    34.8093606, 34.8093592, 34.8093553, 34.8093525, 34.8093678, 
    34.8093428, 34.8093508, 34.8093558, 34.8093472, 34.8093328, 
    34.8093467, 34.8093442, 34.8093447, 34.80934, 34.80934, 34.809345, 
    34.8093422, 34.8093439, 34.8093408, 34.8093158, 34.8093233, 
    34.8093211, 34.8093086, 34.8092881, 34.8093108, 34.8093131, 
    34.8093239, 34.8093239, 34.8093314, 34.8093186, 34.8093364, 
    34.8093186, 34.8093467, 34.8093569, 34.8093422, 34.8093547, 
    34.8093297, 34.8093392, 34.8093439, 34.8093422, 34.8093467, 
    34.8093667, 34.8094836, 34.8095058, 34.8095117, 34.8095081, 
    34.8095286, 34.8096594, 34.8097367, 34.8097419, 34.8097383, 
    34.8097344, 34.8097567, 34.8097383, 34.8097333, 34.8097442, 
    34.8097522, 34.8097133, 34.8097389, 34.8103383, 34.8103183, 
    34.8103242, 34.8102325, 34.8100172, 34.8100922, 34.8100464, 
    34.8100297, 34.8098828, 34.8098272, 34.8098678, 34.8098325, 
    34.8098678, 34.8098803, 34.8098294, 34.8098769, 34.8098661, 
    34.8099208, 34.8098097, 34.8098119, 34.8098222, 34.8097869, 
    34.8097839, 34.8097947, 34.8097719, 34.8097936, 34.8098008, 
    34.8097625, 34.8097858, 34.8097767, 34.8097994, 34.8097969, 
    34.8097936, 34.8098258, 34.8097767, 34.8098044, 34.80978, 
    34.8097853, 34.8098294, 34.8097881, 34.8098119, 34.8097778, 
    34.80978, 34.8097778, 34.809775, 34.8097778, 34.8098028, 
    34.8097908, 34.8098244, 34.8097339, 34.8097947, 34.8098111, 
    34.8097397, 34.8097669, 34.8098044, 34.8097736, 34.8097914, 
    34.8098006, 34.8098036, 34.8098017, 34.8098539, 34.8099175, 
    34.809905, 34.8099483, 34.8095167, 34.8090203, 34.8087753, 
    34.8085189, 34.8084233, 34.8083789, 34.8083319, 34.8082767, 
    34.8082386, 34.8083158, 34.8081128, 34.8080883, 34.8080936, 
    34.8081628, 34.8083425, 34.8084272, 34.8084719, 34.8083322, 
    34.8083053, 34.8083294, 34.8082003, 34.8081542, 34.8082639, 
    34.8086886, 34.8087972, 34.8088972, 34.808895, 34.8090672, 
    34.8091078, 34.8091747, 34.8093692, 34.8093053, 34.8092008, 
    34.8091797, 34.8092061, 34.8092061, 34.8092261, 34.8092267, 
    34.8092436, 34.8092392, 34.8092289, 34.8092231, 34.8095853, 
    34.8100986, 34.8101686, 34.8101936, 34.8104183, 34.8104483, 
    34.8104233, 34.8106097, 34.8105814, 34.8108025, 34.8108572, 
    34.8108572, 34.8108025, 34.8108617, 34.8107975, 34.8108542, 
    34.810975, 34.8111342, 34.8115781, 34.8116769, 34.8116325, 
    34.8116269, 34.8116953, 34.8119767, 34.8119719, 34.8120839, 
    34.8121022, 34.8123353, 34.8123358, 34.8123256, 34.8121886, 
    34.8121858, 34.8121128, 34.8121428), step = c(4949.62076181496, 
    4949.62076181496, 4948.8191145948, 4948.61574446479, 4949.40145487212, 
    4949.59383553208, 4948.24246476737, 4950.78346056595, 4950.24340951536, 
    4949.9136692517, 4950.28369452369, 4951.28178131854, 4950.21579611938, 
    4949.88140017367, 4949.84282611588, 4949.76511333654, 4949.55284471973, 
    4949.21570672672, 4949.51590706933, 4950.51090044315, 4950.84400236867, 
    4953.39161074344, 4952.55873538478, 4952.80799246003, 4954.08097642973, 
    4956.33095287373, 4953.94085909281, 4953.67934573527, 4952.72580239756, 
    4952.61620091734, 4951.67633349252, 4952.98124609379, 4951.23652383642, 
    4953.09162143509, 4950.32205279678, 4949.2015834918, 4950.72298330998, 
    4949.45207112176, 4952.21609633629, 4950.93777244179, 4950.29422096117, 
    4950.72298330998, 4950.21579611938, 4947.67596561717, 4934.96507363034, 
    4932.71880008375, 4932.75077404841, 4933.78989648177, 4931.87602604855, 
    4918.47860124555, 4911.21755383647, 4910.76535819287, 4911.25022243935, 
    4911.94853675613, 4909.24263129925, 4911.1343855871, 4911.7985877645, 
    4910.61939002681, 4909.87014835644, 4914.12756335945, 4911.08632006356, 
    4852.95610844567, 4857.16764718102, 4856.67635281468, 4865.24417654521, 
    4893.09717265052, 4885.70529428402, 4890.63355209235, 4891.99657203824, 
    4910.37035827448, 4916.10191146114, 4911.93116553969, 4915.52294643771, 
    4910.94814954042, 4909.5714660207, 4915.85184628409, 4910.11972110704, 
    4911.72772692499, 4905.64794692137, 4918.30692288626, 4918.1945117151, 
    4916.93047276206, 4920.94735983045, 4921.83148763589, 4920.10724744401, 
    4922.60377576317, 4920.18456022232, 4919.53108534356, 4923.93485234815, 
    4921.40385478506, 4922.20200937773, 4919.57093188919, 4919.99969485447, 
    4920.18456022232, 4916.49496791808, 4922.20200937773, 4919.02505846402, 
    4921.87310587496, 4921.15483782311, 4915.99385934584, 4920.71670260728, 
    4918.47825690135, 4922.26274250034, 4922.15712198275, 4922.12475206037, 
    4922.41896225826, 4922.40720954373, 4919.23254864057, 4920.85802992978, 
    4916.96226263557, 4924.94749967243, 4917.87144842471, 4916.72186212568, 
    4924.61272494986, 4922.02699937693, 4917.90140080115, 4921.40509646529, 
    4917.78644385791, 4917.24748978338, 4916.92924304529, 4913.68437617494, 
    4907.92547903011, 4896.4548800242, 4896.83005641658, 4891.70660310853, 
    4936.32402175659, 4984.92438526935, 5008.84504697386, 5037.92752689217, 
    5047.11542395822, 5052.14304147379, 5056.67887770335, 5061.1928224976, 
    5064.31052222394, 5053.33294902529, 5075.14810709262, 5077.38627527546, 
    5076.40188494856, 5068.55882592794, 5048.40073203715, 5037.46310239395, 
    5032.13269178592, 5044.6187095019, 5048.6454774416, 5045.52212729093, 
    5059.52596101581, 5065.56575454683, 5054.02262784268, 5009.54386771965, 
    4999.42496104349, 4987.85152298424, 4988.51323737934, 4972.30766313851, 
    4968.00341127638, 4961.23170762764, 4940.91441426738, 4948.91640385581, 
    4960.97717262874, 4964.04257613499, 4960.95565036356, 4960.95565036356, 
    4959.03894438886, 4958.68785543541, 4957.10558450316, 4957.30663286492, 
    4959.34149604189, 4960.16732678734, 4919.09386436862, 4862.1848928047, 
    4856.61605813028, 4853.96132820662, 4829.9732464348, 4827.31737063973, 
    4830.0776327334, 4811.46952676529, 4814.56537736019, 4791.68919954049, 
    4786.46237210665, 4787.53938180448, 4794.31294469731, 4787.39144948294, 
    4794.01695628841, 4787.85996869171, 4775.64426741569, 4758.54975662994, 
    4708.20173014285, 4697.39149270334, 4702.18597898211, 4702.17079670057, 
    4696.25421377933, 4671.06745922704, 4671.60993562856, 4659.8067008749, 
    4657.81598337591, 4633.6069387168, 4632.05188939439, 4632.48203915919, 
    4643.99242427024, 4642.10971971687, 4648.89881037161, 4645.90851266969
    ), x = c(88L, 65L, 108L, 144L, 95L, 106L, 33L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 109L, 38L, 0L, 59L, 79L, 14L, 0L, 
    20L, 97L, 115L, 155L, 162L, 166L, 128L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 
    3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 
    9L, 2L, 58L, 43L, 146L, 104L, 104L, 172L, 159L, 194L, 150L, 
    211L, 184L, 190L, 144L, 150L, 111L, 116L, 108L, 156L, 218L, 
    145L, 162L, 231L, 198L, 267L, 243L, 265L, 209L, 223L, 191L, 
    222L, 214L, 213L, 290L, 250L, 171L, 123L, 45L, 77L, 159L, 
    153L, 114L, 158L, 153L, 195L, 201L, 112L, 26L, 121L, 127L, 
    31L, 50L, 110L, 60L, 67L, 115L, 138L, 96L, 123L, 115L, 184L, 
    199L, 210L, 235L, 205L, 211L, 142L, 203L, 211L, 202L, 191L, 
    184L, 184L, 139L, 184L, 204L, 241L, 177L, 143L, 201L, 172L, 
    216L, 166L, 114L, 168L, 198L, 184L, 91L, 121L, 187L, 93L, 
    44L, 51L, 46L, 31L, 88L, 76L, 37L, 54L, 56L, 117L, 49L, 89L, 
    115L, 103L, 53L, 79L, 87L, 48L, 29L, 72L, 49L, 121L, 65L, 
    155L, 173L, 73L, 69L, 74L, 33L, 67L, 46L, 23L, 53L, 177L, 
    243L, 188L, 237L, 164L, 148L, 166L, 188L, 203L, 215L, 189L, 
    111L, 108L), y = c(71L, 48L, 89L, 68L, 69L, 118L, 31L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 229L, 68L, 0L, 107L, 186L, 
    22L, 0L, 17L, 109L, 85L, 165L, 108L, 95L, 124L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 33L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 111L, 23L, 71L, 57L, 61L, 148L, 120L, 164L, 98L, 
    97L, 161L, 153L, 165L, 129L, 84L, 194L, 275L, 243L, 170L, 
    268L, 121L, 174L, 185L, 283L, 259L, 250L, 174L, 182L, 165L, 
    217L, 212L, 209L, 323L, 248L, 114L, 85L, 85L, 89L, 286L, 
    129L, 140L, 132L, 181L, 164L, 117L, 155L, 14L, 135L, 107L, 
    31L, 37L, 78L, 29L, 34L, 81L, 87L, 60L, 179L, 222L, 199L, 
    123L, 198L, 161L, 116L, 213L, 131L, 211L, 203L, 196L, 182L, 
    142L, 179L, 152L, 173L, 198L, 360L, 152L, 107L, 327L, 192L, 
    313L, 118L, 130L, 123L, 241L, 215L, 73L, 190L, 183L, 103L, 
    13L, 30L, 35L, 17L, 66L, 71L, 17L, 61L, 50L, 100L, 33L, 65L, 
    123L, 68L, 32L, 56L, 72L, 49L, 13L, 63L, 44L, 56L, 46L, 136L, 
    149L, 52L, 42L, 53L, 24L, 45L, 35L, 12L, 63L, 291L, 268L, 
    174L, 214L, 155L, 119L, 149L, 256L, 302L, 187L, 183L, 104L, 
    119L), z = c(114.258972095821, 80.8563608035899, 141.048198832708, 
    159.805857508397, 117.90682321211, 159.275993423285, 47.1135061278318, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.47213595499958, 0, 253.666016940687, 
    81.1594168812644, 0, 124.172000675193, 202.112042375532, 
    26.0768096208106, 0, 26.2678229983099, 154.060779809137, 
    143.267785574523, 228.009237062229, 194.895223495878, 192.242143263573, 
    179.056894372315, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35.3847096529504, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 10, 7, 3, 6, 0, 0, 2, 7, 8, 12, 3, 1, 
    7, 9, 1, 8, 9, 2, 127.295553819089, 51.7958125154422, 162.695770021952, 
    121.306207841974, 122.229047927423, 228.015606348372, 200.021787692648, 
    256.030925370097, 179.275090894152, 233.078150888214, 245.921872404178, 
    246.406641365101, 220.272633774893, 198.124447034996, 139.948878046849, 
    229.96835082335, 296.60916407034, 297.962893436887, 276.617091164528, 
    305.965408404764, 202.495250616183, 289.34186900663, 271.87350743739, 
    393.217666567627, 371.02887318756, 373.476394566051, 273.08647816276, 
    289.712383980657, 255.30297030913, 312.250442802713, 301.252850437501, 
    301.57813686341, 434.231038426784, 353.029494979685, 206.750768052738, 
    150.206871465948, 96.6803808056206, 118.239371697801, 331.6897153079, 
    200.680690256219, 182.620288944353, 210.39036616987, 242.101361850306, 
    257.457473278128, 233.743367491713, 192.168067766683, 29.5296461204668, 
    185.725658479653, 168.811680547801, 45.6719701706192, 63.4528560775242, 
    135.73143304185, 66.7216687049813, 75.3513250512419, 140.895894786181, 
    163.592719962869, 113.671682275045, 222.246248552452, 250.416178708983, 
    272.57944153163, 234.525703510054, 291.898905648915, 285.434778991709, 
    235.746129174462, 303.016946989874, 193.627056627229, 293.829246674915, 
    293.202568120954, 281.812070651277, 264.949484681642, 234.082680647222, 
    257.300989383049, 205.980480957584, 254.14934347046, 284.542646009499, 
    437.55633027441, 237.276291890275, 179.050512323281, 384.350222403635, 
    259.221186131464, 381.780946697182, 203.682316426828, 175.493098802349, 
    208.719398998353, 312.104747693392, 285.530241990153, 118.293813276872, 
    226.118487194746, 262.679897701864, 139.383238221394, 46.1101811610523, 
    59.2784161522187, 58.4450975919519, 35.3709062650989, 110.066424497602, 
    104.688788719604, 41.1214223865412, 85.8719963432696, 75.4070040155068, 
    154.733559259088, 60.2041968611235, 110.271243752022, 170.018905352777, 
    125.142263269443, 63.6003731330296, 98.1413276676947, 113.400604652918, 
    68.9909717449211, 32.2447874858287, 95.8666604735184, 66.4901151502835, 
    133.762066230643, 80.5181028859729, 206.511388497782, 229.023940423869, 
    90.6038363290751, 80.832522038745, 91.0438085849357, 40.9275161449154, 
    80.9378801806903, 58.0156034102918, 26.4722050542442, 84.0596245397044, 
    341.992193326017, 364.649258507904, 256.198388467479, 323.08626829894, 
    226.599117393241, 190.43296701921, 223.180193751852, 321.054020030441, 
    370.624429352703, 285.63087542605, 263.757552801897, 152.329281695877, 
    160.960989723506)), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 2L, 
`9` = 9L, `12` = 12L, `47` = 47L, `60` = 60L, `61` = 61L, `65` = 65L, 
`106` = 106L, `109` = 109L, `111` = 111L, `112` = 112L, `120` = 120L, 
`122` = 122L, `124` = 124L, `125` = 125L, `126` = 126L, `127` = 127L, 
`128` = 128L, `130` = 130L, `131` = 131L, `132` = 132L, `133` = 133L, 
`135` = 135L, `136` = 136L, `137` = 137L, `138` = 138L, `139` = 139L, 
`140` = 140L, `141` = 141L, `142` = 142L, `143` = 143L, `155` = 155L, 
`156` = 156L, `157` = 157L, `170` = 170L, `178` = 178L, `183` = 183L, 
`483` = 483L, `1731` = 1731L, `2633` = 2633L, `2635` = 2635L, 
`2641` = 2641L, `2646` = 2646L, `2648` = 2648L, `2668` = 2668L, 
`4585` = 4585L, `4673` = 4673L, `5518` = 5518L, `6855` = 6855L, 
`6902` = 6902L, `6917` = 6917L, `7919` = 7919L, `8464` = 8464L, 
`8471` = 8471L, `8493` = 8493L, `8747` = 8747L, `8771` = 8771L, 
`8774` = 8774L, `8791` = 8791L, `9294` = 9294L, `10135` = 10135L, 
`10311` = 10311L, `11091` = 11091L, `11331` = 11331L, `11571` = 11571L, 
`11575` = 11575L, `12651` = 12651L, `12787` = 12787L, `13461` = 13461L, 
`13469` = 13469L, `13820` = 13820L, `14435` = 14435L, `14446` = 14446L, 
`14447` = 14447L, `14473` = 14473L, `14474` = 14474L, `14476` = 14476L, 
`14479` = 14479L, `14480` = 14480L, `14482` = 14482L, `14486` = 14486L, 
`14734` = 14734L, `14736` = 14736L, `14742` = 14742L, `14795` = 14795L, 
`14802` = 14802L, `15342` = 15342L), class = "omit"), row.names = 639:839, class = "data.frame")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have numerical row names? Try `nrow(dataresults)`  and also `tail(row.names(dataresults))` . Is the name of the last row the same as the number of the last row?

Comment: I agree with G5W. Try removing row names by `rownames(dataresults) <- NULL` then doing the same manipulation.